# QtPy QCalendarWidget on arrow clicked

Tags: python, calendar

Can I run a method when the user clicks to see the next month in the calendar?

not the `calendar.clicked.connect(self.Method)`, which is when a user clicks on a date, but when he clicks the arrow at the upper left/right corner to go to next or previous month.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcalendarwidget.html

Comment: @tmoreau Do you see anywhere to say when this happens? You think I did not look there? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the code is this:

```
 self.calendarWidget.currentPageChanged.connect(self.YOUR_METHOD)
```